# PHP check "variable variables" isset

Tags: php, reflection, isset

For normal variables I can use isset($var) to check if it is set.

How to check if a variable variable (a variable that have the name stored in another variable) is set?

Comment: The exact same way …?

Comment: Do you **really** need variable variables?

Comment: `isset($$var)`?

Comment: Nobody needs variable variables. There's arrays.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/jbIQU variable variables are generally a bad practice, not sure of your use case but they can almost always be avoided

Comment: in my case, is a private include that can have or not some parameters as variable variables. an array would do the same work with more noise. For my case variable variables are ok, but still not have the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this:

```
if(isset(${$variable_name})...
```